# bulid and run the web app didn't work with facebook sdk

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I'm trying to integrate a facebook sdk in my Unity 4.6 project ,i tried to login with facebook and its' working correctly in play mode, but when I tried to bulid and run the web app it didn't work.. any suggestions ??

Answer (score 0):

Where is your "web app" hosted? If it's not inside the Facebook Canvas (apps.facebook.com/yourapp), the SDK does not work....